# Save undo stack during macro run

Tags: vba, excel, undo

I am wondering if there is a way to save ability to undo actions after macro has been run.
I do not care about results of macro - just need to undo actions that were done by user before macro.

Background:
I have a macro on the worksheet_change event that logs who and when made the change on this worksheet. I do not want it to restrict user's ability to undo his/her actions.

Comment: Nope, unless you keep track of the changes yourself. That means, unless you track everything user has been doing somewhere (either within the workbook or a separate file).\

Comment: I haven't tried it, but see [this](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/UndoWithVBA00.asp) and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ef5ac45-9c62-4f17-a074-e9e8326941b0/capture-undo-history-before-event-in-excel) for some background.

Comment: As long as the change event doesn't write to the current sheet then the undo actions for that sheet work anyway. Ie log to another sheet should be fine.

Comment: Hi, did the answer below help? That seems to be the only way to get it done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this, but it's possible. The approach to this is to create three macros, and use some global variables to save state:

1. MyMacro
2. MyStateSavingMacro
3. MyStateRevertingMacro

E.g. My macro changes Cells in Range **A1:A10** of the active sheet. So, whenever the code to run my macro is called, it executes

```
Sub MyMacro()       
    Call MyStateSavingMacro() 
    ' Copies contents and formulae in range A1:A10 to a global data object

    '... Code for MyMacro goes here
    '
    '................

    Call Application.OnUndo("Undo MyMacro", "MyStateRevertingMacro")
    'This puts MyStateRevertingMacro() in the Undo queue
    'So pressing ctrl-Z invokes code in that procedure
End Sub


Sub MyStateSavingMacro()
    ' Code to copy into global data structures anything you might change
End Sub

Sub MyStateRevertingMacro
    ' Code to copy onto the spreadsheet the original state stored in the global variables
End Sub
```

So there it is. It's not pretty, but can be done.
Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194135%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Edit:
To preserve the Undo queue prior to your MyMacro being run, the inelegant solution would be to create a chain of 4-5 `MyStateRevertingMacro_1`, _2, etc. where you can apply the information from your Worksheet_Change logging system and then chain-up the `Application.OnUndo` in each of those, so `Application.OnUndo` for each of those Reverting Macros would refer the previous state reversion code.

Comment: As horrible as this is, there's something worse - even if you DO go to all of this trouble... you still can't undo anything you did before the macro.  All undo history is wiped the second you run any macro or add-in.  I've no idea WHY Microsoft hasn't fixed this, in 20+ years?  Does it pose a security risk for some reason?  Seems like it should be trivial for them to save the global workbook state before the macro runs ‍♂️

Answer (score 3):

You can use the hidden mirror sheet to do this. Of course it will work if your worksheet is simple enough. You must decide which cells are editable and copy them TO mirror sheet, which are not editable and copy them FROM mirror sheet. And your macro should work only in the mirror sheet. That's it.

Comment: Good option - I like it. But I can't imagine it working with the huge model.

Answer (score 0):

This one is a bit old now but in case anyone is still trying to get this to work - I just tried setting the undo stack to be able undo the formatting on a column that a macro had reformatted and noticed that by doing that the full undo command worked (before I added this bit the undo was unavailable) - does not matter what the custom undo code contains (in my case I had not even created the routine yet), the application undo works perfectly

`Application.OnUndo "Undo Amount Format", "sUndo_Col2"`

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Where in my code should I put it?

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C9:C10000")) _
          Is Nothing) Then
            Application.OnUndo "Undo Amount Format", "sUndo_Col2"
            Target.Value = VBA.UCase(Target.Value)
    End If
End Sub