# Undo all actions of a button VSTO

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-addins, undo-redo

I am developing a MS Word Add-In, so I added a button that fires a function :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) {
    // do some actions on a word document (text - formatting - ...) here.
}
```

My issue is, when the funcation performs `n` actions on the word document, I have to click undo `n` times to undo all button actions. This is a bad user experience to undo like 10 or 100 times to return to original state (text - formatting - ... etc).

Is there some way to pack all button actions as one action in the undo stack, so that I can undo button effect with a single click or `Ctrl + z` ?

### Important note:

An alternative approach that **does the job for me** is to:

- Open **temp** document.
- Copy **original** document to **temp** document.
- Do all edits on **temp** doc ( `n` actions taken on it).
- Copy **temp** doc back to **original** doc (only one action taken which is `paste`, so I can undo it).

This is why I struggled in the second approach: [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66081189/full-word-document-copy-in-vsto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap everything in a custom undo-record - that way you only have to undo once to undo it all.

Visual Basic:

```
Application.UndoRecord.StartCustomRecord "Title of undo-record here"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Optional, reduces screen flicker during operations.

'--- Your code here

Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Optional, but required if set to false above
Application.UndoRecord.EndCustomRecord

' After this, you can undo once to undo it all.
```

C#:

```
Application.UndoRecord.StartCustomRecord "Title of undo-record here";
Application.ScreenUpdating = false; // Optional, reduces screen flicker during operations.

//--- Your code here

Application.ScreenUpdating = true; // Optional, but required if set to false above
Application.UndoRecord.EndCustomRecord;

// After this, you can undo once to undo it all.
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent to it in C# ?

Comment: @AhmedHussein It's the same in C#, just add a semicolon at the end of each line, and replace ' with // for the comments :-)

Answer (score 0):

This StackOverFlow Answer should point you in the right direction.

[Save undo stack during macro run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185942/save-undo-stack-during-macro-run)

Comment: This cannot be applied for some types of document changes. For example, I cannot revert the actions taken by a button that performs some regex replacements on document text.