# Full word document copy in VSTO

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

I am trying to copy a word document to another without closing the target document. So, I do it like that:

```
temp_doc_.Content.Copy();
target_doc_.Content.Paste();
temp_doc_.Close(SaveChanges: false);
```

However, this doesn't copy some features like margins, header height, ... etc. It only copies section paragraphs. Does anyone know how to do a full copy so that they are really identical in everything ?

Comment: To see what's required for that, visit: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43339-combine-multiple-word-documents.html. The code there is VBA, but that will give you and idea of what's involved.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying just the body of the document, instead, use Document.SaveAs2 ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas2?view=vsto-2017

Comment: I don't want to "save", I want to "copy"

Comment: SaveAs creates a new file, with a new name and retains all of the settings of the source file. The source file stays intact, exactly as it was when you opened it.

Comment: After thinking about it, I must not be understanding something. The document you are pasting into, does it already exist? Are you pasting in additional content but you want to change the margin settings of the target to match the source? If so, you have to programmatically reset them.

Comment: I have a target_doc_ that has some paragraphs. I want to modify a lot of things in it programatically (fonts - margins - headers - tab stops - ... ) without touching the "undo stack" of target_doc_. So, I am doing the following:

1- copy all text into temp doc

2- do whatever I want to temp_doc_

3- Copy temp_doc_ to target doc "this adds single action to target_doc_ undo stack"

4- Close temp_doc_
All of this without closing target_doc_

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will do the margins, but it WILL do the headers and footers.

```
Word.Document tempDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open('tempdoc.docx');
Word.Document targetDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open('targetdoc.docx');

tempDoc.Activate();
tempDoc.Application.Selection.WholeStory();
tempDoc.Application.Selection.Copy();

targetDoc.Activate();
targetDoc.Application.Selection.WholeStory();
targetDoc.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, and even header text is not copied. Are you sure you tested it?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the open document without closing it, and without affecting it's "saved"-state.

`filePath` could be in the temp-folder or similar.

`sourceDocument` must be a `Microsoft.Word.Document` instance.

VB

```
Dim persistFile = CType(sourceDocument, Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IPersistFile)
persistFile.Save(filePath, False)
```

C#

```
var persistFile = (Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IPersistFile)sourceDocument;
persistFile.Save(filePath, False);
```

Then just open the copied file and you have a complete clone of the entire document.

Comment: The only issue with this answer is it assumes that `persistFile` isn't already opened. That is, I have both files (source + destination) opened while doing the clone process. Got it?

Comment: No, persistfile creates a copy of the already open document and saves it to disk as a cloned document. Since you are creating the new document in that process, by definition, it can't already be open. We use this for when we need to store a copy of the document as it is, without modifying any document content or properties in the process. It is quite reliable.

Comment: If you want to transfer document content from one open document-instance to another open document-instance, there is *a lot* more involved, often traversing properties one-by-one, with custom handlers for each type of properties. And even then you will likely never be able to copy everything, there is always another property hidden somewhere that you missed, that only exists in some edge-case. Believe me, we do this is one of our solution, and we've been expanding our cloning method for YEARS, still not complete. For example, we just found out that document themes are difficult to copy. *sigh*

Comment: - And you can't just use reflection to loop all properties recursively, since lots of properties are read-only and has to be set via setter-methods. And even reading some properties will simply cause Word to crash - not just throw an exception, but crash completely. It is a mess to say the least.

Comment: I sent you a connection request on LinkedIn, can we get in touch please?