# 2 Questions: How could I add a vba save undo line to my code? Can I specify a range, and have it run the same code increasing one of the #s each time?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two things I'm trying to accomplish and have searched around to piece it together but I'm not getting as far as I would like.

The code below monitors when there is a change in a cell, then enters the date in the cell next to it aka the date it was updated. I only have it running on the 3 cells to test and it seems to work like I want. However since it runs a vba command I think it deletes the undo stack. Is there an easy way to have it save the undo stack so afterwards you could still undo the user made change? If I wanted to get even crazier I'd get it to undo the date change as well, but for now I don't think its as important.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 11 And Target.Row = 29 Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(29, 12).Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    End If
    If Target.Column = 11 And Target.Row = 30 Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(30, 12).Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    End If
    If Target.Column = 11 And Target.Row = 31 Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(31, 12).Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    End If
End Sub
```

The other thing I want to do, instead of just running this on 3 cells. I need it to run on about 400 more cells below it which would mean copying and pasting this and adding 1 to each row of code. Is there a way I could define a range and use one line of this code to do them all?

Hopefully this makes enough sense.

Thank you if anyone knows and is willing to share a potential solution for this!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185942/save-undo-stack-during-macro-run

Comment: For the second (and, really you should post two questions if you have two questions), look into looping through the cells.

Comment: Ah, I was reading that link earlier but I guess didn't understand it enough. Il try see if I can get it to apply to what I'm doing.

And my bad, I'll do separate questions next time. Thanks for the tip though!