# Undo after VBA action occurs

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, when a cell in columns A, B, C, E, or F is updated, the cell in column D of that row will return the date/time of the last update.

However, I am unable to "undo" any changes made within the range. Is this possible?

VBA Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myTableRange As Range
Dim myUpdatedRange As Range

'Your data table range
Set myTableRange = Range("A:C,E:F")

'Check if the changed cell is in the data tabe or not.
If Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Stop events from running
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Column for last updated date/time
Set myUpdatedRange = Range("D" & Target.Row)

'Update the updated date/time value
myUpdatedRange.Value = Now

'Turn events back on
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: no, it is not possible to undo changes done by code.  The only thing to do would be to create a copy of the data on another sheet then run another code that replaces the new with the old.

Comment: Could you share the reason why (in which case) you would want to undo?

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good discussion of this in another Stack Overflow post:

[Save undo stack during macro run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185942/save-undo-stack-during-macro-run)

It's not pretty, but some folks have found solutions that work in their contexts.